# How to make login authentication in RESTful API CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have built one Restful API using CakePHP for interfacing my mobile app. I'm now having problem in verifying the login of users in the API. I used 'BlowfishPasswordHasher' to hash the password, is there a way to decrypt it with same mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

A hash is usually always a one way ticket, so no you can't.

REST is stateless so use a token (lookup JWT token for example) for authentication.